# SWFUpload multiple files server-side handling

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, server-side, swfupload

I need the user to be able to upload multiple files to my server, thus I am using the `SWFUpload` utility. SWFUpload sends the files one by one, and I need to store them all in the same temporary directory. My `ASP.NET` handler recieves the files one by one and I can store the file appropriately.

My problem is: How do I know which files belong to the same upload? Rephrased, how do I connect the files in my handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 ways to do this (but they inherit the same idea).

The idea is based on the thing you should have something like `sessionId` parameter. This value should be unique for each set of files. You could use `javascript` `uuid` generators or something like so.

Further, this `sessionId` variable may be passed through query string(a little bit modified your handler url): `~/UploadHandler.ashx?sessionId={whatever}` or as post parameter(guess, the better way).
The value may be retrieved on the server side by using: `context.Request["SessionId"]` for example.

On the client side you should be able to change post parameters or handler url dynamically. It could be done by using:

```
void addPostParam(name, value)
```

> The addPostParam function adds a
>   name/value pair that will be sent in
>   the POST for all files uploaded.
>
> The name/value pair will also appear
>   in the post_params setting.

or

```
void setUploadURL(url)
```

> Dynamically modifies the upload_url
>   setting.

client methods. They should be called from the

```
fileDialogComplete(number of files selected, number of files queued, total number of files in the queued)
```

> The fileDialogComplete event fires
>   after the File Selection Dialog window
>   has been closed and all the selected
>   files have been processed. The 'number
>   of files queued' argument indicates
>   the number of files that were queued
>   from the dialog selection (as opposed
>   to the number of files in the queue).

method.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: @Alex: Thank you for your suggestion. I had a feeling that this was the approach I needed to take, but had hoped for some magic :)